# Creatine and Protein Intake

Tags: workout, protein, protein-shakes, creatine, whey

I have read on numerous websites that taking creatine and whey protein together adds no [benefit](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/creatine-vs-whey), but then something does not make sense to me.

Muscles are made up of protein, when you drink protein shake after a workout, that protein goes towards building muscles. But creatine does not contain any protein, so how will the muscles get bigger? Where will the protein come from to make them bigger? If I do not consume protein shake with creatine, do I need to add extra protein to my diet?

Answer (score 1):

I think the article somewhat took this out of context. It seems after checking the studies that in women and middle-aged men, that taking protein seems to increase the muscle and strength, so does creatine. Lets say for an easy example they gained an extra 2lbs of muscle on protein supplements, and the other group also gained 2 extra lbs of muscle, but the group that took both also gained 2 extra lbs. The logic seems to be that after 8 weeks of training, its not necessary to take both supplements. Understand that these studies are small, and I cannot find many other examples. The test subjects are also older. There seem to be too many variables, the women were already in shape and trained for only 8 weeks. the older group(42-72) trained for 14 weeks but because of their age, perhaps the body is limited and can only gain so much strength and muscle, no matter how many supplements you're adding.

Yes, you need protein to build muscle, but these test subjects are not necessarily bodybuilders, so having enough protein from their diet along with just creatine supplementation is enough to induce growth according to the studies, even without the additional protein. muscles are built with diet, not just supplementation. carbs and protein help build muscles. There are some bodybuilders that dont even use protein shakes, so it's not a requirement. I'm curious what other websites you found this on?

when you eat food you get your protein. protein shakes are not necessary, so if you skip a protein shake, you're still able to build muscle as long as you aren't malnourished

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So if I got it right, creatine alone would not give us muscle mass if our aim is to get bigger, we need an increased protein intake (either from the diet or shakes).
You asked for some references. Here is what I have seen

1- https://www.elo.health/articles/should-you-add-creatine-to-protein-powder/#can-you-mix-creatine-with-protein-powder
2- https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12603-009-0124-8
3- https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1186/1550-2783-10-S1-P20

Comment: Creatine does not create mass. What it does is provide extra energy in the muscle to do more work, which in turn can help create bigger muscles.